# What are some interesting examples of wrong or crazy inferences being drawn from Big Data?

Tags: dataset, large-data

I'm interested in well-known examples of Big Data misinterpreted, poorly analysed, or wrongly employed to unscientific and incorrect ends. Would appreciate any examples or observations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: some examples of spurious correlations at this web site http://www.tylervigen.com/

Answer (score 2):

One example could be Google's failure to predict flu trends. See for instance [this Guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/mar/27/google-flu-trends-predicting-flu).